# Two child delete on a binary tree

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that requires manually implementing a binary tree with pointers.  My tree works great right up to the point of deleting with two children.  What I end up with at that point is the correct item is removed and the correct item is put in place of the removed item, but I am ending up with the left child being an incorrect pointer to itself and I can not figure out where I am messing this up.  I do not want to post all of the code because this is an assignment, but here is the code that has the problem.  If someone could please point me to where I am making my mistake without just doing the code for me I would really appreciate it.  Also the tree I am testing with looks roughly like this and I am attempting to remove node 3.  Node 2 is in place as it should be, but node 2 left is node 2.  I could see how to get around this in this case, but then it would be messed up if the replacement node was not the direct child so I am not seeing what I am doing wrong.

```
       5
     /   \
   3       7
 /  \     /  \
2    4   6    8
   /   
 3.5

temp = delItem->left;
back = delItem;
while(temp->right != NULL)
{
    back = temp;
    temp = temp->right;
}

returnItem->m_dValue = delItem->m_dValue;
returnItem->m_dWeight = delItem->m_dWeight;
returnItem->m_iType = returnItem->m_iType;
strcpy(returnItem->m_sDesc,delItem->m_sDesc);
strcpy(returnItem->m_sItemName,delItem->m_sItemName);
returnItem->left = delItem->left;
returnItem->right = delItem->right;
delItem = temp;
delItem->left = returnItem->left;
delItem->right = returnItem->right;
returnItem->left = NULL;
returnItem->right = NULL;
        /*delItem->left = left;
        delItem->right = right;*/
if(back == delItem)
{
    back->left = temp->left;
}
else 
{
    back->right = temp->left;
}
temp->left = NULL;
temp->right = NULL;
delete temp;
return returnItem;
```

Thanks for any help because everything I see either talks about the theory, which I understand just fine or does not come close to fixing the issue.

Jimmy

Comment: What are the variable you are using? What dWeight and iType are meant to be? Are you referrin to just "binary tree" or to a particular implemetation  like black&red or AVL?

Answer (score 1):

Removing an item from a binary tree is covered in many places over the internet (and textbooks).

I would suggest taking a look at these links, as they do provide code examples either. It is very important that you understand the algorithm, as since it is an assignment, you are expected to know it and could be tested on it in the future.

[Binary search tree. Removing a node](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Removal)

[Binary Tree – Deleting a Node](http://www.tech-faq.com/binary-tree-deleting-a-node.html)

Comment: I understand the algorithm perfectly and have already been tested on it and made a 100.  I know what I am attempting to do as well.  I am attempting to follow the left branch to the right most item, which is done successfully.  I also know based on the algorithm which nodes I want to set for children.  What I do not see is what mistake I am making in doing that.  I have been through dozens of websites and all the books I have.  It is not an explanation issue.  It is that I am setting a pointer wrong and I can not see where that is happening.  I was at both of these sites before posting as well